# Need to access docker engine that is running in one system from another system

Tags: java, python, docker

I like to run,start or stop a container in docker that is running in another system. I like to know how to do it. My use case is I like to create docker container dynamically for each request. If the container is created for a particular request I like to use the same container. Could it be accessed using api requests? if so what port should i connect to? I need to do this from java

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could indeed use the API. If dockerd on the other system is run using `dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0`, the default port is `2375`. You can also specify a port though (e.g. `dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376`).

Make sure you know the security implications. If you don't apply any security at all, anyone can use your Docker system for anything. Here's the official documentation on how to secure dockerd daemons running like this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/